# Checking for WildCards in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script on which I am trying to remove links that follow hardcoded and wildcard characters.

```
$Skip = "http://test.com","http://server/Main/*"
$Site = Get-SPSite
foreach($Skip - notcontains $Site)
{
  //Do Something
}
```

How can I make sure that it validates http://server/Main/* as wildcard and does not process if $Site is http://server/Main/Test.something or http://test.com

Thanks

Comment: You are probably better of using a regular expression for that. Unless someone else comes up with a brilliant idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-like` operator:

```
$Skip = "http://test.com","http://server/Main/*"
$Site = Get-PSSite
$Process = $True

$Skip | Foreach-Object {
    if($Site.Url -like $_){ 
        $Process = $False 
    }
}
if($Process){
    # Do Something
}
```

Comment: @sp9 sorry, it's the `$Site.Url` property you should be checking against, updated answer